# SolrCloud election leader

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I would like to use SolrCloud (Solr4.10.3 ).. I follow this wiki(Example B: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Example_B:_Simple_two_shard_cluster_with_shard_replicas )

> SolrCloud uses leaders and an overseer as an implementation detail.
>   This means that some nodes/replicas will play special roles. You don't
>   need to worry if the instance you kill is a leader or the cluster
>   overseer - if you happen to kill one of these, automatic fail over
>   will choose new leaders or a new overseer transparently to the user
>   and they will seamlessly takeover their respective jobs. Any Solr
>   instance can be promoted to one of these roles.

When I stop the first instance where i run the zookeeper, i can't get another leader.

I get this Info in the same node(Example2 log file) :

```
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.508; org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerElectionContext; I am going to be the leader 192.168.1.38:7574_solr
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.548; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient; makePath: /overseer_elect/leader
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.576; org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer; Overseer (id=93413623381032961-192.168.1.38:7574_solr-n_0000000001) starting
WARN  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.957; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread;    
Session 0x14bdf320ecf0001 for server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9983,    
unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:40.064; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@1537a92 name:ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:localhost:9983 got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path:null type:None
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:40.064; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
```

In other Node (Example2B) i get that in the log file

```
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.507; org.apache.solr.cloud.ShardLeaderElectionContext; Running the leader process for shard shard1
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.553; org.apache.solr.cloud.ShardLeaderElectionContext; Checking if I (core=collection1,coreNodeName=core_node3) should try and be the leader.
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.574; org.apache.solr.cloud.ShardLeaderElectionContext; My last published State was Active, it's okay to be the leader.
INFO  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.578; org.apache.solr.cloud.ShardLeaderElectionContext; I may be the new leader - try and sync
WARN  - 2015-03-03 11:35:39.956; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x14bdf320ecf0002 for server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9983, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

We can see in the the same instance, there is a call for election leader process but it failed.. i don't see the probleme.

How to get automatically another leader?

Is there a special config in my solr server?

How to force the election for another leader?

Thx!

Comment: i get this Warn `I am going to be the leader 192.168.1.38:7574_solr
..INFO  - ; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient; makePath: /overseer_elect/leader
..WARN  - ;unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
..java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: after few search, i'm in the point to use solr with external zookeeper....`Although Solr comes bundled with Apache ZooKeeper, you should consider yourself discouraged from using this internal ZooKeeper in production, because shutting down a redundant Solr instance will also shut down its ZooKeeper server, which might not be quite so redundant. Because a ZooKeeper ensemble must have a quorum of more than half its servers running at any given time, this can be a problem.`

Comment: my objective is to run solr with external zookeeper into 2 host..
I can't terminate this task.. i use this link : [SolrCloud HOWTO](http://solr.pl/en/2013/03/11/solrcloud-howto-2/), [Configure-Solr-Cloud-with-External-Zookeeper](http://mfg-hub.hubpages.com/hub/Configure-Solr-Cloud-with-External-Zookeeper-Step-by-Step-Guide)

Comment: It's not recomended to use embeded zookeeper  for our production.. when we stop a solr instance where run a zookeeper, there is no leader election..we should use external zookeeper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config zookeeper(host : xxx.xxx.xxx.1):

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2181
server.1=127.0.0.1:2888:3888
```

Start Solr1 (host : xxx.xxx.xxx.2)

```
java -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf 
                 -Dcollection.configName=solr1 
                 -Dsolr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading=true 
                 -DzkHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.1:2181 
                 -DnumShards=2 
                 -jar start.jar
```

Start Solr2 (host : xxx.xxx.xxx.3)

```
java -Djetty.port=8900 -DzkHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.1:2181 -jar start.jar
```

Close all firewall !